Getting the clicked marker in react leaflet
So I have my leaflet map in my react project, I have markers on this map and I want to get the marker clicked. I want to show this markers popUp info on a side panel. How would I get the marker clicked? The regular onClick method isn't working?


<div className="m-3 " id="map">
                    <MapContainer center={[35.5820, -80.8140]} zoom={13}>
                        <TileLayer
                            attribution='&copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                            url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                        />

                        <MarkerClusterGroup chunkedLoading >
                            {(addressPoints).map((address, index) => (
                                <Marker
                                    key={index}
                                    position={[address[0], address[1]]}
                                    onClick={handleClick}
                                >
                                    <Popup>
                                        {address[2]}
                                    </Popup>
                                </Marker>
                            ))}
                        </MarkerClusterGroup>
                    </MapContainer>
                </div >




Regular react onClick does not work you must use this


<Marker eventHandlers={{ click: handleClick }} key={index} position={[address[0], address[1]]} onClick={handleClick}>
  <Popup>
    {address[2]}
  </Popup>
</Marker>



